# Summing values in R based on column value with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set that has the following information:

```
Subject    Value1    Value2    Value3      UniqueNumber
001        1         0         1           3
002        0         1         1           2
003        1         1         1           1
```

If the value of UniqueNumber > 0, I would like to sum the values with dplyr for each subject from rows 1 through UniqueNumber and calculate the mean. So for Subject 001, sum = 2 and mean = .67.

```
total = 0;
average = 0;
for(i in 1:length(Data$Subject)){
   for(j in 1:ncols(Data)){
   if(Data$UniqueNumber[i] > 0){
    total[i] = sum(Data[i,1:j])
    average[i] = mean(Data[i,1:j])
   }
}
```

Edit: I am only looking to sum through the number of columns listed in the 'UniqueNumber' column. So this is looping through every row and stopping at column listed in 'UniqueNumber'. 
Example: Row 2 with Subject 002 should sum up the values in columns 'Value1' and 'Value2', while Row 3 with Subject 003 should only sum the value in column 'Value1'.

Comment: You can try `df %>%
 mutate(sum = ifelse(UniqueNumber > 0, rowSums(.[, 2:(length(.)-1)]), NA),
        mean = ifelse(UniqueNumber > 0, rowMeans(.[, 2:(length(.)-1)]), NA))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk I don't think your code will iterate through on the length of the UniqueNumber. It looks like my results are summing through the whole column and not stopping at the value of the column UniqueValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
df %>%
  gather(key, val, Value1:Value3) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(
    Sum = sum(val[c(1:(UniqueNumber[1]))]),
    Mean = mean(val[c(1:(UniqueNumber[1]))]),
  ) %>%
  spread(key, val)
```

Output:

```
 Subject UniqueNumber   Sum  Mean Value1 Value2 Value3
  <chr>          <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 001                3     2 0.667      1      0      1
2 002                2     1 0.5        0      1      1
3 003                1     1 1          1      1      1
```

Comment: How exactly does this gives the correct results? That gives me wrong results when I insert random NAs into the data. For example, try inserting `NA` into `Value1` into the first row.

Answer (score 11):

Not a tidyverse fan/expert, but I would try this using long format. Then, just filter by row index per group and then run any functions you want on a single column (much easier this way).

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Data %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Subject, -UniqueNumber) %>% # long format
  group_by(Subject) %>% # group by Subject in order to get row counts
  filter(row_number() <= UniqueNumber) %>% # filter by row index
  summarise(Mean = mean(value), Total = sum(value)) %>% # do the calculations
  ungroup() 

## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Subject  Mean Total
#     <int> <dbl> <int>
# 1       1 0.667     2
# 2       2 0.5       1
# 3       3 1         1
```

---

A very similar way to achieve this could be filtering by the integers in the column names. The filter step comes before the `group_by` so it could potentially increase performance (or not?) but it is less robust as I'm assuming that the cols of interest are called `"Value#"`

```
Data %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Subject, -UniqueNumber) %>% #long format
  filter(as.numeric(gsub("Value", "", variable, fixed = TRUE)) <= UniqueNumber) %>% #filter
  group_by(Subject) %>% # group by Subject
  summarise(Mean = mean(value), Total = sum(value)) %>% # do the calculations
  ungroup()

## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Subject  Mean Total
#     <int> <dbl> <int>
# 1       1 0.667     2
# 2       2 0.5       1
# 3       3 1         1
```

---

Just for fun, adding a data.table solution

```
library(data.table)

data.table(Data) %>% 
  melt(id = c("Subject", "UniqueNumber")) %>%
  .[as.numeric(gsub("Value", "", variable, fixed = TRUE)) <= UniqueNumber,
    .(Mean = round(mean(value), 3), Total = sum(value)),
    by = Subject]

#    Subject  Mean Total
# 1:       1 0.667     2
# 2:       2 0.500     1
# 3:       3 1.000     1
```

Comment: Edit: Looks like few subjects didn't have UniqueValues. Need to check this. Everything is working well!

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to deal with missing values? Also, is it possible to calculate the mean with a denominator taking in to account the missing values?

Comment: What do you mean by missing values? `NA`s in the `Value` column? Just add `na.rm = TRUE` to the functions, e.g. `summarise(Mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), Total = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))`. Not sure I understand your second question. Can you please show an example with desired output?

Comment: Oh ok, that's what I thought. And if I wanted to modify the "Mean" column to modify the denominator of the mean function by +1 or -1, is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean but you could do `summarise(Total = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), Mean = Total / n())`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method that uses `tidyr::nest` to collect the `Values` columns into a list so that we can iterate through the table with `map2`. In each row, we select the correct values from the `Values` list-col and take the sum or mean respectively.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
"Subject    Value1    Value2    Value3      UniqueNumber
001        1         0         1           3
002        0         1         1           2
003        1         1         1           1"
)
tbl %>%
  filter(UniqueNumber > 0) %>%
  nest(starts_with("Value"), .key = "Values") %>%
  mutate(
    sum = map2_dbl(UniqueNumber, Values, ~ sum(.y[1:.x], na.rm = TRUE)),
    mean = map2_dbl(UniqueNumber, Values, ~ mean(as.numeric(.y[1:.x], na.rm = TRUE))),
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   Subject UniqueNumber Values             sum  mean
#>   <chr>          <dbl> <list>           <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 001                3 <tibble [1 × 3]>     2 0.667
#> 2 002                2 <tibble [1 × 3]>     1 0.5  
#> 3 003                1 <tibble [1 × 3]>     1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

OP might be interested only for `dplyr` solution but for comparison purposes and for future readers a base R option using `mapply`

```
cols <- grep("^Value", names(df))

cbind(df, t(mapply(function(x, y) {
      if (y > 0) {
        vals = as.numeric(df[x, cols[1:y]])
        c(Sum = sum(vals, na.rm = TRUE), Mean = mean(vals, na.rm = TRUE))
       }
       else 
        c(0, 0)
},1:nrow(df), df$UniqueNumber)))

#  Subject Value1 Value2 Value3 UniqueNumber Sum  Mean
#1       1      1      0      1            3   2 0.667
#2       2      0      1      1            2   1 0.500
#3       3      1      1      1            1   1 1.000
```

Here we subset each row based on its respective `UniqueNumber` and then calculate it's `sum` and `mean` if the `UniqueNumber` value is greater than 0 or else return only 0.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that uses `purrr::map_df`(which is from the same author as `dplyr`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
l_dat <- split(dat, dat$Subject) # first we need to split in a list

map_df(l_dat, function(x) {
  n_cols <- x$UniqueNumber # finds the number of columns
  x <- as.numeric(x[2:(n_cols+1)]) # subsets x and converts to numeric
  mean(x, na.rm=T) # mean to be returned
})
# output:
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#     `1`   `2`   `3`
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.667   0.5     1
```

Another option (output format closer to a `dplyr` solution):

```
map_df(l_dat, function(x) {
  n_cols <- x$UniqueNumber
  id <- x$Subject
  x <- as.numeric(x[2:(n_cols+1)])
  tibble(id=id, mean_values=mean(x, na.rm=T))
})
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# id mean_values
# <int>       <dbl>
# 1     1       0.667
# 2     2       0.5  
# 3     3       1
```

---

Just as an example I added a `sum()` then divided by `length(x)-1`:

```
map_df(l_dat, function(x) {
  n_cols <- x$UniqueNumber
  id <- x$Subject
  x <- as.numeric(x[2:(n_cols+1)])
  tibble(id=id, 
                mean_values=sum(x, na.rm=T)/(length(x)-1)) # change here
})
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# id mean_values
# <int>       <dbl>
# 1     1          1.
# 2     2          1.
# 3     3        Inf  #beware of this case where you end up dividing by 0
```

Data:

```
tt <- "Subject    Value1    Value2    Value3      UniqueNumber
001        1         0         1           3
002        0         1         1           2
003        1         1         1           1"

dat <- read.table(text=tt, header=T)
```

Comment: Receive the following error when I run your code:

Error in 2:(n_cols + 1) : NA/NaN argument

Comment: I don't have this error, have you tried it on my example data? If your "UniqueNumber" column is named differently you need to change this part `x$UniqueNumber` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I my data had a missing column so the code crashed. Went back and fixed the issue, it works!

Comment: Can you modify the denominator of the 'mean' function so that it divides by 1 less? I need to include the first value (i.e. Value1), but it's a starting point. So I would like to divide by one less in each instance (while still removing the NAs).

Comment: @statsguyz yes you can, you can do whatever you want inside the function, just change mean() with whatever you like, I'll update with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to set to `NA` the zeros that really should be `NA`, then use `rowSums` and `rowMeans` on the appropriate subset of columns.

```
Data[2:4][(col(dat[2:4])>dat[[5]])] <- NA
Data
#   Subject Value1 Value2 Value3 UniqueNumber
# 1       1      1      0      1            3
# 2       2      0      1     NA            2
# 3       3      1     NA     NA            1

library(dplyr)
Data%>%
  mutate(sum  =  rowSums(.[2:4], na.rm = TRUE),
         mean = rowMeans(.[2:4], na.rm = TRUE))

#   Subject Value1 Value2 Value3 UniqueNumber sum      mean
# 1       1      1      0      1            3   2 0.6666667
# 2       2      0      1     NA            2   1 0.5000000
# 3       3      1     NA     NA            1   1 1.0000000
```

or `transform(Data, sum = rowSums(Data[2:4],na.rm = TRUE), mean = rowMeans(Data[2:4],na.rm = TRUE))` to stay in base R.

**data**

```
Data <- structure(
  list(Subject = 1:3, 
       Value1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), 
       Value2 = c(0L, 1L, NA), 
       Value3 = c(1L, NA, NA), 
       UniqueNumber = c(3L, 2L, 1L)), 
  .Names = c("Subject","Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "UniqueNumber"),
  row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```